# How to send an email with Rabbitmq-email

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq

I need to send an email to some people when some data changes and I have to use rabbitmq-email, but I can't find an example ( in javasript ) to understand how to use it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Take a look at the SMTP plugin here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/community-plugins.html

Comment: There isn't a an example

Comment: Did you see the docs here? https://github.com/gotthardp/rabbitmq-email